# Drawing this Image in my Java Applet wont work

Tags: java, image, applet

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class MonoplyDriver extends JApplet {

boolean isFirst=true;
Player John = new Player(1500,"Circle","John");
Board board = new Board();
Image imgBoard;

public void init()
{
    //imgBoard = new ImageIcon("res/board.png").getImage();
    imgBoard = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"res/board.png");
    setSize(750,750);
    System.out.println(getDocumentBase());
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    //super.paint(g);
    if(isFirst)
    {
        isFirst=false;
    }
    g.drawImage(imgBoard, 0, 0, this);

}
```

}

Comment: Where is the image `res/board.png` actually stored?  Is it packaged within the Jar or on the web server?

Comment: The board.png is stored in the res folder, under the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it, the image is not being found because it is a internal resource.

You could try something like...

```
imgBoard = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/board.png"));
```

This will throw an `IOException` if the image cannot be loaded for some reason, which is more useful than what you're getting right now

As an aside.  You should avoid painting directly to top level containers, but instead using something that extends from `JComponent` and override it's `paintComponent` method

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: Thank You! I wish i could upvote you but i don't even have enough reputation. Simple path error...